# Union for storing Timestamp. Comparing floats as integers

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, timestamp, unions

While trying to wrap my brain around a custom game engine, I stumbled across a piece of code that looks rather odd to me:

```
union TimeStamp
{
    f32 asFloat;
    u32 asUInt;

    TimeStamp() : asUInt(0U)
    {}

    TimeStamp(f32 floatValue) : asFloat(floatValue)
    {}

    operator u32() const { return this->asUInt; }

    inline const bool operator==(const TimeStamp& other) const { return this->asUInt == other.asUInt; }
    inline const bool operator!=(const TimeStamp& other) const { return this->asUInt != other.asUInt; }

    inline const bool operator<(const TimeStamp& other) const { return this->asFloat < other.asFloat; }
    inline const bool operator>(const TimeStamp& other) const { return this->asFloat > other.asFloat; }

};
```

My c++ experience(which is quite limited) tells me that the only meaningful reason to have this union is to make equality operators to treat compared timestamps(otherwise float) as integers? If yes, then why would someone want that?

I also don't understand what is the point of an integer type cast overload here, since we can't event init Timestamp with int?

**Note:** `f32` and `u32` are defined as `float_t` and `uint32_t`

Just in case, here is a link containing the definition: https://github.com/tobias-stein/EntityComponentSystem/blob/master/EntityComponentSystem/include/ECS/Platform.h

Comment: You can only read form a union member if it was the last member to be assigned to. So if `.asFloat` was last assigned to, any call to a member function that reads `asUInt` can't be called and vice-versa. This `TimeStamp` type is almost unusable.

Comment: Seems like this code rely on UB (which does work on some platforms).

Comment: It looks like they want to use float to store the value, but use integer equality tests to avoid floating point errors (not casting float to int but using float bits as integer bits). Maybe?

Comment: You know, there are lots of bad code on the internet. I believe you found an example. It is not clear what it is aiming to do, and it is certainly unreliable due to variables used without initialization...

Comment: This may be an ancient optimisation, where float comparison could be much slower than integer comparison. So long as the float is not a special INF or NAN value, or a very small denormal, OR ZERO, the binary representations would be the same and the int compare would be faster. Of course the way float can represent both positive and negative zero would be a concern to me.

Comment: The speed downside, compared to sticking with one format: if if any method uses the equality test and uses the float value, then the compiler will not be happy to optimise all the code to registers.

Comment: @GemTaylor That was my thinking as well. But is it reasonable to compare two floats with no margin allowed? Seems that by subtracting integer representations of two equally signed floats, you can get a number(minus one) of representable floats between them, which then can be compared to some arbitrary value. But that doesn't explain the "hard" equality above.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I believe that if the intention was to avoid the rounding errors, they would've introduced some relative value acting as a boundary.

Comment: @Constantineous Who knows? We aren't mind readers! :-) Perhaps the level of equality was good enough for their purposes at that time. If we are only talking float, then you have to accept a restricted accuracy anyway, depending on your epoch. secs/day needs 13 bits, days/year needs 5 bits, 100 years need 7 bits, so something's gotta give!

Comment: @GemTaylor I must admit, I don't understand your example. I mean the relation between time intervals and bits.